# Changing show-hide script so that it works on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, show-hide

I'm using this script to show/hide menu sections on my page but it doesn't seem to work on Internet Explorer. How can I change the code so that it works on IE as well?

I think that this could be done in Jquery much more easily with the toggle function but I'd like to keep the same structure, can anyone help me out?

```
visibleDiv1 = "";
visibleDiv2 = "";
visibleDiv3 = "";
visibleDiv4 = "";

function showHide1(elementid1){
  if (document.getElementById(elementid1).style.display == 'none'){
    document.getElementById(elementid1).style.display = '';
    if(visibleDiv1 != ""){
      if(visibleDiv1 != elementid1){
        document.getElementById(visibleDiv1).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    visibleDiv1 = elementid1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(elementid1).style.display = 'none';

  }
}

function showHide2(elementid2){
  if (document.getElementById(elementid2).style.display == 'none'){
    document.getElementById(elementid2).style.display = '';
    if(visibleDiv2 != ""){
      if(visibleDiv2 != elementid2){
        document.getElementById(visibleDiv2).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    visibleDiv2 = elementid2;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(elementid2).style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function showHide3(elementid3){
  if (document.getElementById(elementid3).style.display == 'none'){
    document.getElementById(elementid3).style.display = '';
    if(visibleDiv3 != ""){
      if(visibleDiv3 != elementid3){
        document.getElementById(visibleDiv3).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
visibleDiv3 = elementid3;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(elementid3).style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function showHide4(elementid4){
  if (document.getElementById(elementid4).style.display == 'none'){
    document.getElementById(elementid4).style.display = '';
    if(visibleDiv4 != ""){
      if(visibleDiv4 != elementid4){
        document.getElementById(visibleDiv4).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    visibleDiv4 = elementid4;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(elementid4).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really poorly coded, you need to re-use your code, and simply call the elements you want to hide.  You have created functions for EACH element.

You should have done a primary function like this:

```
function showHide(elementid, visibleDiv){
  if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
    document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
    if(visibleDiv != ""){
      if(visibleDiv != elementid1){
        document.getElementById(visibleDiv).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
    visibleDiv = elementid;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';

  }
}
```

and later simply call that function doing something like:

```
showHide('id-of-your-element', 'visible-div-etc');
```

I would really suggest grabbing jQuery tho, as this *simple* hidding stuff is better supported right out of the box, and you can focus on other things.  Use `toggle()` or just plain `.hide()` / `.show()` functions.

Comment: Much better! I did try to use a Jquery script to do the same but I was having problems closing the sibling divs when clicking a new one. I actually found out what was the problem with the code, it seems IE doesn't like IDs that start with numbers so I added a prefix to them and it's functioning now.

Comment: umm... a name/variable (id/class) CANNOT be a number, its programming, a variable cannot be `12 = "hello"`.  It is common sense.

Comment: @S3nd41, if you like my answer btw, check the GREEN checkbox under the vote up/down buttons.

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out what was going on, it had nothing to do with this.